# Spyder internal error while trying to open array

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, anaconda, spyder, tensorflow-datasets

I am working on my Deep learning project. My code runs fine but when I try to open array such as X and Y variable in this case, it shows this error and the values can't be seen.

[image]

I tried reinstalling anaconda, resetting spyder `spyder --reset`
I got this while upgrading spyder

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\durgesh>conda update spyder 
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done 
Solving environment: - Updating spyder is constricted by anaconda -> requires spyder==3.2.8=py35_0
```

Whenever I open Spyder I get a pop up that Spyder 4.0.0 is available but for Python 3.5 it requires Spyder 3.2.8

Python 3.5.5
Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Please run `conda update anaconda` and then `conda install spyder=3.3.6`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Sir it gives some conflicts regarding the versions what to do then